# Correct way to detach from a container without stopping it

Tags: docker

In Docker 1.1.2 (latest), what's the correct way to detach from a container without stopping it?

So for example, if I try:

- `docker run -i -t foo /bin/bash` or
- `docker attach foo` (for already running container)

both of which get me to a terminal in the container, how do I exit the container's terminal without stopping it?

`exit` and `CTR+C` both stop the container.

Comment: The "container" is just a set of restricted namespaces (a process namespace, a filesystem namespace, etc) that processes can run in. If you have no process inside of a namespace, does that namespace really exist? It's not like a virtual machine where there's a kernel answering clock interrupts &c. regardless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you attach and detach from Docker's process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688314/how-do-you-attach-and-detach-from-dockers-process)

Answer (score 241, accepted):

**Update:** As mentioned in below answers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> will now turn interactive mode into daemon mode.

---

Well <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>) should detach you from the container but **it will kill the container** because your main process is a bash.

A little lesson about docker.
The container is not a real full functional OS. When you run a container the process you launch take the PID 1 and assume init power. So when that process is terminated the daemon stop the container until a new process is launched (via docker start) (More explanation on the matter http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/#intro)

If you want a container that run in detached mode all the time, i suggest you use

```
docker run -d foo
```

With an ssh server on the container. (easiest way is to follow the dockerizing openssh tutorial https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)

Or you can just relaunch your container via

```
docker start foo
```

(it will be detached by default)

Comment: +1 for baseimage-docker. It's great to know there's a template with advice about the hard parts of Docker.

Comment: Note that ssh isn't strictly necessary: http://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/

Comment: I had forgotten about nsenter. Feel free to edit the answer to add more detail on the subject.

Comment: running a contained in -d mode was very helpful. Also, the link to start ssh via Dockerfile made my life easy.

Comment: Yeah, I won't -1 but it does not reply to the question: How to detach form a docker container?

Comment: *Detach* using Ctrl-p, Ctrl-q. This answer's advice will kill a container.

Comment: This worked for me (taken from answer below): Start with `-ti -d`, then attach with `docker attach`, then detach with *first* ctrl+p *and then* ctrl+q. I thought, I could use just one of the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Note that if you accidentally killed a container, you can use `docker ps -a` to get the container id and `docker commit YOUR_ID SOME_NAME` to get the container back with the file system changes in tact.

Comment: The info in this answer is helpful, thank you. Further below is another answer which works in docker v23.0.1 Linux. If I attach to an already running container using `docker container attach --sig-proxy=false mycontainer` CTRL-C will detach without stopping the container. To start and detach at once I use `docker container start mycontainer;docker container attach --sig-proxy=false mycontainer`.

Answer (score 686):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>. It will help you to turn interactive mode to daemon mode.

See at the [Default key-sequence to detach from containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#default-key-sequence-to-detach-from-containers) section that indicates:

> Once attached to a container, users detach from it and leave it running using the using `CTRL-p CTRL-q` key sequence. This detach key sequence is customizable using the `detachKeys` property. [...]

Comment: It seems to not work for with (trying to exit an attached Wekan container).

Comment: I've visited this page so times because I could not remember this key combination precisely ! :-D

Comment: @danger89 ctrl-p, ctrl-q will only work when you have started your container with interactive mode (-it). If you've started it in deamon mode (-d) and attached to it, you can just exit it and it will still run in the background.

Comment: @SlimShady press Ctrl + P then, Ctrl + Q to exit, not one of them but, both in that order.

Comment: I've confirmed it works for a container created as `docker run -itd <imagename>` too

Answer (score 231):

I dug into this and all the answers above are partially right.  It all depends on how the container is launched.  It comes down to the following when the container was launched:

- was a TTY allocated (`-t`)
- was stdin left open (`-i`)

### `^P^Q` *does work, BUT* only when `-t` and `-i` is used to launch the container:

```
[berto@g6]$ docker run -ti -d --name test python:3.6 /bin/bash -c 'while [ 1 ]; do sleep 30; done;'
b26e39632351192a9a1a00ea0c2f3e10729b6d3e22f8e0676d6519e15c08b518

[berto@g6]$ docker attach test
# here I typed ^P^Q
read escape sequence

# i'm back to my prompt
[berto@g6]$ docker kill test; docker rm -v test
test
test
```

### `ctrl+c` *does work, BUT* only when `-t` (*without* `-i`) is used to launch the container:

```
[berto@g6]$ docker run -t -d --name test python:3.6 /bin/bash -c 'while [ 1 ]; do sleep 30; done;'
018a228c96d6bf2e73cccaefcf656b02753905b9a859f32e60bdf343bcbe834d

[berto@g6]$ docker attach test
^C

[berto@g6]$
```

### The third way to detach

There is a way to detach without killing the container though; you need another shell.  In summary, running this in another shell detached and left the container running `pkill -9 -f 'docker.*attach'`:  (NB! the -9 for sigkill is vital to stop the "attach" process from propagating the signal to the running container.)

```
[berto@g6]$ docker run -d --name test python:3.6 /bin/bash -c 'while [ 1 ]; do sleep 30; done;'
b26e39632351192a9a1a00ea0c2f3e10729b6d3e22f8e0676d6519e15c08b518

[berto@g6]$ docker attach test
# here I typed ^P^Q and doesn't work
^P
# ctrl+c doesn't work either
^C
# can't background either
^Z

# go to another shell and run the `pkill` command above

# i'm back to my prompt
[berto@g6]$
```

Why? Because you're killing the process that connected you to the container, not the container itself.

Comment: third way works for me. Thanks. 

if you are attaching to several instances and only want to detach from one. Can kill the specific process:

ps -ef | grep attach 
-> get pid. Then:
kill -9 <pid>

Comment: pkill is the only thing that worked for me after docker attach

Comment: Why do we need the -9. I noticed if we dont use the -9 it shutsdown the container.

Comment: Other signals are that, signals.  They tell the process what type of signal and give it a chance to act and do something. The `kill -9` signal doesn’t.  The process is terminated and has no recourse.  My guess is that other signals give the container a chance to shut down, while `-9` does not.

Comment: I'd replace `while [ 1 ]` by `while true`. The `[` command, a.k.a `test` command does not do what you expect there. Both `[ 0 ]` and `[ 1 ]` have zero as return code, so the loop executes. `true` and `false` are commands that, respectively, succeed and fail at doing nothing.

Answer (score 50):

If you do "docker attach "container id" you get into the container.
To exit from the container without stopping the container you need to enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

Comment: better to Ctrl+P and Ctrl+Q

Comment: Ctrl+P, Q(still holding Ctrl) ;)

Comment: it returns me: `Error response from daemon: Container f560a0ad6806150b2775d0b6e6d5f7065a03775bae858fb4fb7df05a277976db is not running`

Answer (score 36):

I consider Ashwin's answer to be the most correct, my old answer is below.

---

I'd like to add another option here which is to run the container as follows

```
docker run -dti foo bash
```

You can then enter the container and run bash with

```
docker exec -ti ID_of_foo bash
```

No need to install sshd :)

Comment: I think in the second command you need to replace foo with the container id of foo

Comment: In this context, I think `docker attach` would be more standard, by reattaching to the first bash run. `docker exec` also works here, however it creates a new bash process in addition to the first one. Sure, the process is created within the same context / environment / container of the first one, however it is a different one (an analogy would be to open a new terminal tab in your favorite terminal emulator).

Comment: This is the only command that worked for my specific scenario. Running a test suit in Docker using VS Code. In my case it was a Rails app, so to start the background container `docker-compose run -d --name app_tests app spring server`, and then I could run tests by setting the vscode test command to `docker exec -ti app_tests spring rspec`

Answer (score 32):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>,<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to turn interactive mode to daemon.

If this does not work and you attached through `docker attach`, you can detach by **killing the `docker attach` process**.

Better way is to use sig-proxy parameter to avoid passing the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to your container :

```
docker attach --sig-proxy=false [container-name]
```

Same option is available for `docker run` command.

Comment: Though **--sig-proxy=false** is extremely useful, it doesn't work for already-attached containers for which it wasn't specified. The problem is, after attaching there seems to be NO way to detach without killing the process, including "killing the docker attach process." C-p,C-q doesn't work with attached containers, only interactive ones (like the question uses).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, including @taranaki 's comment, Ctrl+P,Q does not work for `php:7.3-apache`

Answer (score 24):

The default way to detach from an interactive container is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, but you can override it when running a new container or attaching to existing container using [the --detach-keys flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#override-the-detach-sequence).

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `--detach-keys` option when you run `docker attach` to override the default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> sequence (that doesn't always work).

For example, when you run `docker attach --detach-keys="ctrl-a"  test` and you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> you will exit the container, without killing it.

Other examples:

- `docker attach --detach-keys="ctrl-a,x"  test` - press `CTRL+A` and then `X` to exit
- `docker attach --detach-keys="a,b,c"  test` - press `A`, then `B`, then `C` to exit

**Extract from the official documentation:**

If you want, you can configure an override the Docker key sequence for detach. This is useful if the Docker default sequence conflicts with key sequence you use for other applications. There are two ways to define your own detach key sequence, as a per-container override or as a configuration property on your entire configuration.

To override the sequence for an individual container, use the `--detach-keys="<sequence>"` flag with the docker attach command. The format of the `<sequence>` is either a letter `[a-Z]`, or the `ctrl-` combined with any of the following:

- a-z (a single lowercase alpha character )
- @ (at sign)
- [ (left bracket)
- \ (two backward slashes)
- _ (underscore)
- ^ (caret)

These `a`, `ctrl-a`, `X`, or `ctrl-\\` values are all examples of valid key sequences. To configure a different configuration default key sequence for all containers, see [Configuration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files) file section.

*Note: This works since docker version 1.10+ (at the time of this answer, the current version is 18.03)*

Answer (score 16):

If you just want see the output of the process running from within the container, you can do a simple `docker container logs -f <container id>`.

The `-f` flag makes it so that the output of the container is `followed` and updated in real-time. Very useful for debugging or monitoring.

Comment: thanks for this, the `ctrl+p+ctrl+q` didn't work for me for some reason.

Answer (score 10):

***In Docker container atleast one process must be run***, then only the container will be running the docker image(ubuntu,httd..etc, whatever it is) at background without exiting

**For example in ubuntu docker image ,**

**To create a new container with detach mode (running background atleast on process),**

```
docker run -d -i -t f63181f19b2f /bin/bash
```

it will create a new contain for this image(ubuntu) id `f63181f19b2f` . The container will run in the detached mode (running in background) at that time a small process `tty` bash shell will be running at background. so, container will keep on running untill the bash shell process will killed.

**To attach to the running background container,use**

```
docker attach  b1a0873a8647
```

if you want to detach from container without exiting(without killing the bash shell),
By default , you can use `ctrl-p,q`. it will come out of container without exiting from the container(running background. that means without killing the bash shell).

**You can pass the custom command during attach time to container,**

```
docker attach --detach-keys="ctrl-s" b1a0873a8647
```

this time `ctrl-p,q` escape sequence won't work. instead, `ctrl-s` will work for exiting from container. you can pass any key eg, `(ctrl-*)`

Comment: I've been switch tabs between Stack Overflow answers on this topic multiple times and this is the simplest, easy, complete, and straight-to-the-point answer. Thank bro

Answer (score 2):

To prevent having logs you should run in detach mode using the `-d` flag

```
docker run -d [container-name]
```

If you are already stuck, you could open a new window/tab in your terminal and close the first one. It won't stop the process of the running job

Answer (score 1):

You can simply kill docker cli process by sending SEGKILL. If you started the container with

`docker run -it some/container`

You can get it's pid

`ps -aux | grep docker`

```
user   1234  0.3  0.6 1357948 54684 pts/2   Sl+  15:09   0:00 docker run -it some/container
```

let's say it's 1234, you can "detach" it with

`kill -9 1234`

It's somewhat of a hack but it works!

Answer (score 0):

in case if you using docker on windows, you may use combination 'CTRL + D'

Comment: You could format the keyboard shortcut using [`<kbd>`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270967/5493813)