# How to disown a docker container running inside SSH session

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh

I have accessed a Remote Machine (call it , RM) through SSH (from my host). And I am running a docker image inside RM via my SSH session. Both are Ubuntu 16.04 based.

There are some processes running inside this docker container, so I can't exit the container.

So,how do I detach this ssh session from my host, so that those processes inside the docker would still run unaffected.

I am doing this, because I have to restart my host machine for some purpose.

PS:
In this link [Correct way to detach from a container without stopping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267372), it's not running the docker container via SSH session. So two scenarios are different.

Comment: If you run your container in detached mode (with the -d flag), then exiting your SSH session will not affect it.

Comment: Yeh.. but I have already started the container without -d flag and was running bash inside it. So, any way to disown it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to detach from a container without stopping it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267372/correct-way-to-detach-from-a-container-without-stopping-it)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to start your `Docker` container in daemon (non-interactive) mode, using `-d` argument and dropping `-it`. Don't forget to name your container for further usage with `--name foo` option.

After container is started, you can control it using `docker exec -it foo sh-or-whatever`. If your `ssh` session will terminate, container will continue running. However, you `docker exec` session will be over.

Comment: What if the docker was already started without -d mode. How do I make it a daemon now.

Comment: Just restart it

Comment: Not possible, as I am running a process inside it, which should not be killed and it would take many days to complete.