# Cannot start simple docker container with "docker start" command from created image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have simple commands for making and starting container (create.sh):

```
docker build -t foo .

docker rm bar
docker create --name=bar foo && \
docker start bar && \
docker exec bar sh /bin/echo Test!!!
```

Dockerfile:

```
#/bin/bash
FROM centos:7
RUN yum update -y
```

But it cannot be started:

```
$ bash create.sh
Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB
Step 1 : FROM centos:7
 ---> 980e0e4c79ec
Step 2 : RUN yum update -y
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 80b94205920c
Successfully built 80b94205920c
bar
a1db507225ca7479bdcc3bb3d4e3a86339827f4bf0e9365f507978b11d99df19
bar
Error response from daemon: Container bar is not running
```

The container has been created but it hasn't started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Dockerfile for CentOS](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/6df5e76a6403483f2ce463c11c36d98d7d957886/docker/Dockerfile) specifies the shell as the `CMD` to run when you start a container:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Docker containers exit when the process they started with finishes, so what's happening is when you `start` your container, it runs `bash` and then ends, because there's no more input to the shell.

Using your Docker image, this does what you expect - the `echo` command overrides the `bash` command in the Dockerfile:

```
> docker run temp echo 'Test'
Test
```

If you want to keep a container running in the background, then you need the process inside the container to keep running. You can specify a command when you create the container:

```
 >docker create temp sleep infinity
a34a4528b3cfbb7a36fb429d32510c5576831adeb899c07e4596a6b9731c945b
> docker start a34
a34
> docker exec a34 echo 'Test'
Test
```

Answer (score 4):

Your Dockerfile has no ENTRYPOINT or CMD, so it finishes immediately, that is normal.

Check the docs about ENTRYPOINT

Comment: extract from the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd `The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.`

Comment: from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint `An ENTRYPOINT allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable.
For example, the following will start nginx with its default content, listening on port 80:

docker run -i -t --rm -p 80:80 nginx`

Comment: Hm, it's still not clear. Do you mean this container stops immediately because there is tasks in background? Like nginx, apache, etc.

Comment: No the container stops because he has completed what it had to do, see a basic nginx Dockerfile at https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile it has as last line `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` or see https://hub.docker.com/r/k3ck3c/nethogs/ it launches nethogs, by default on wlan0, but can also run on eth0 or ra1

Comment: the last line of the docker mysql https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/9f95658f528699d2c2017ca42ad163a9d5c5e7c1/5.7/Dockerfile launches the mysql daemon, as `CMD ["mysqld"]`

Comment: if you have no action, the docker container exists

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. So, I didn't know it should be stopped after finished all tasks. I found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d