# Acess bash docker-compose with Centos Image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I Build an dockerfile for centos7 and a docker-compose file for linking volumes to the container and set some local variables. When i start the container with

```
docker-compose up --build
```

My dockerfile does its work. After starting the container it exits with Exitcode 0.

I want to acess my container by shell. How can i do that without terminating the container and staying open?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum -y update
CMD /bin/sh
```

My Composer file:

```
version: '2'
services:
 media:
  build: .
  volumes:
   - ./media:/media
   - ./media/bin/x86_64/release/:/usr/local/lib/
  command: bash
  environment:
   - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib
  expose:
   - "8080"
   - "80"
   - "443"
```

Any ideas?

To keep it open in a normal docker usage is explained already, but not in context to the usage with docker-compose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker container will automatically stop after "docker run -d"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d)

Comment: it is not a duplicate because of the usage of Docker-compose in this context . Run as a normal docker container works a expected, but how to keep it open in a docker-compose context it isn't explained.

Comment: Does it stay up if you run it with `docker run -d`? That's what Docker Compose does. It should terminate once the yum update has completed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `docker-compose run` instead of `docker-compose up`.

```
$ docker-compose run --rm media /bin/bash
[root@54eb39f672c7 /]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

`docker-compose up` is used to start a service which is always running.

On the other hand, `docker-compose run` is used to run a one-off command.

`docker-compose run` does not have the option of `--build`.
If you want to change the Dockerfile and the rebuild the image, use `docker-compose build`.

Comment: thank you, this would work if windows is not docker host, it doesnt support interactive mode for docker-compose yet

Answer (score 0):

Add -d to run in detach mode

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```