# Docker Container(Dockerfile from other image) immediately exit - It is all about Dockerfile not command

Tags: docker, redmine, docker-container

I am trying to run `Redmin` via `docker`.

Here is what I am going to do

1. Copy `redmine:latest` docker image to custom image
2. Do some extra setting and make a container
3. Run the custom docker container

So I made `Dockerfile` like

```
FROM redmine
CMD ["echo", "Redmine is ready!"]
```

Then I built image with `docker build -t test .`.(In the `Dockerfile` folder)

After that, `docker run -d --name=test -p 8080:3000 test`.

I expected can find `test` docker container is `run` state, but it is `exit(0)`.

How can I make this container keep alive?

FYI, `docker run -d --name=test -p 8080:3000 redmine` works fine.

Comment: Your container runs the CMD and exits. That is why you get this behavior.

Comment: Take a look at this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/30209974/1561148](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30209974/1561148)

Comment: @tgogos To me, `FROM` keyword feels little bit unclear. According to [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from), it is about basic image. So I have presumed that running `test` image will execute original jenkins `Dockerfile` `CMD`. So I thought it should execute `CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]`. So is there any way to execute Dockerfile `CMD` command of the original image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker container will automatically stop after "docker run -d"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your docker image CMD can be used only once. 
If you have more than one, only the last one will run.

You will need to add the

```
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

As the cmd for your custom image to run the server. At the moment your CMD only executes echo as soon as that command is executed your container will exit.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much