# Raspberry PI docker container not starting

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

I built docker image as per https://github.com/hypriot/rpi-node using command `./build.sh` .

After build can see the images :

```
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hypriot/rpi-node               7.6.0-onbuild       3bc1143b2669        8 minutes ago       486MB
hypriot/rpi-node               7.6.0-slim          f0e665843753        8 minutes ago       201MB
hypriot/rpi-node               7.6.0               561d1c96f866        9 minutes ago       486MB
hypriot/rpi-node               6.10.0-onbuild      e914857026be        9 minutes ago       482MB
hypriot/rpi-node               6.10.0-slim         76f21b654bbb        9 minutes ago       197MB
hypriot/rpi-node               6.10.0              8358e50b084c        10 minutes ago      482MB
hypriot/rpi-node               4.8.0-onbuild       d7d1ed3d2745        11 minutes ago      477MB
hypriot/rpi-node               4.8.0-slim          fc4fcfe4dfe3        11 minutes ago      192MB
hypriot/rpi-node               4.8.0               0879c967512d        13 minutes ago      477MB
```

Attempting to run an image using 6.10.0 : `sudo docker run hypriot/rpi-node:6.10.0` does not return any output but the container is not running as executing `docker ps` returns empty response.

How to start `rpi-node` docker container ?

Update :

this appears to fix : `sudo docker run -dti hypriot/rpi-node:6.10.0 tail -f /dev/null`

Source : [Docker container will automatically stop after "docker run -d"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this appears to fix : `sudo docker run -dti hypriot/rpi-node:6.10.0 tail -f /dev/null`

Answer (score 0):

It would appear as if the images have a default `CMD` of `node` according to https://github.com/hypriot/rpi-node/blob/master/6.10/Dockerfile#L94. Just running the image would try to execute `node`. This would normally run the Node.js REPL. But it would require an interactive terminal.

Try running as `sudo docker run -it hypriot/rpi-node:6.10.0` instead to set interactive mode and a TTY.

Comment: thanks but same issue when use ' sudo docker run -it hypriot/rpi-node:6.10.0 ' - no error being reported