# Docker stop after start with daemon process

Tags: python, docker

I have a small `Gunicorn` service. This is my `Dockerfile` for it:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=POSIX

RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y upgrade \
&& apt-get install -y python-pip \
&& mkdir /app


ADD . app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "--config", "/app/gunicorn.py", "myrun:app", "&&", "tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

The problem is I can't hold the container as the active process. I run it so: `docker run --name pypypy -td -p 8187:8081 pytest`.

What do I do wrong ? I read [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d) at stackoverflow. But it doesn't work for me and I don't know why.

Comment: what's the container output?

Comment: @whites11 just one string with id. Something like `bc95a716f2309b1ff0624af28efce442eb89e0c21e88202a1059f8bd4b0a3762`.

Comment: yeah, thats the container ID. try running the image without the "-d" flag to get the standard output

Comment: I'm not sure but I doubt that the `CMD` is passed to a shell, so the `&&` will not be evaluated as you expect it but instead will be passed verbatim as argument to `gunicorn` which will probably be surprised and thus terminate quickly.

Comment: Try the SHELL form of CMD rather than EXEC "CMD 
 /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --config /app/gunicorn.py myrun:app && tail -f /dev/null"

Answer (score 0):

Did you decide to add the `&& tail -f /dev/null` or is that copied from another `Dockerfile` example? My assumption is that this is an attempt to keep `tail` as the active process, waiting forever on the null device after starting `gunicorn` in the background?

Anyway, I'm pretty sure that is an unnecessary addition if your purpose is just to have a single-process container with `gunicorn` running inside. For example, [this blog post](https://sebest.github.io/post/protips-using-gunicorn-inside-a-docker-image/) on the topic seems to show `gunicorn` running just fine as a non-daemon within a container. You **might** be able to get the `&& tail..` method working, but I think it is actually cleaner to just have the gunicorn process running, and maybe for more "Docker best practice" alignment, use the logging setup from that blog post so that `docker logs` work properly with your containerized `gunicorn` process.