# Docker container shutting down upon start

Tags: tomcat, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I am trying to build and run container where I can start tomcat ( I know I can find direct image but wanted to do by my own for learning )

When I am running it, it's getting down automatically,

I checked log, it says Tomcat started

```
docker build -t hanuman .

docker run -i -t  -p 80:8080  hanuman 

docker run -i -t  -p 80:8080  hanuman --entrypoint /bin/sh tail -f /dev/null
```

### **My Docker file**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk

ADD tomcat8 /usr/local/tomcat8

RUN cd home

RUN ls -lrt

RUN chmod 777 -R /usr/local/tomcat*

EXPOSE 8080 8009 443

ENTRYPOINT  ./usr/local/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh start
```

Comment: why are you tailing `/dev/null`?

Comment: without tail also it dosent work, somewhere I red that since there nothing to do container shunting down, and suggested there to do so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `catalina.sh run` such that the process does not terminate. `start` would start tomcat in background and then terminate.

```
ENTRYPOINT  ./usr/local/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh run
```