# Difference between docker run and docker container run

Tags: docker

Can anyone help me in the understanding difference between **docker run** & **docker container run**?

when i do **docker run --help** & **docker container run --help** from docker cmd line. I see the following

**Run a command in a new container**.

Is there any difference in how they run the container internally or both are same doing same work?

As per https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-run-and-docker-container-run/30526. **docker run** is still the old one, which will be deprecated soon but same is not confirmed.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

They are exactly the same.

Prior to docker 1.13 the `docker run` command was only available. The CLI commands were then refactored to have the form `docker COMMAND SUBCOMMAND`, wherein this case the COMMAND is `container` and the SUBCOMMAND is `run`. This was done to have a more intuitive grouping of commands since the number of commands at the time has grown substantially.

You can read more under [CLI restructured](https://www.docker.com/blog/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/).

Comment: Link has changed: https://www.docker.com/blog/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/ for those that want to know :)

Answer (score 10):

> docker run no, we aren't even hiding it, it's staying as a permanent alias.
>
> The rest, not any time soon. Maybe in a year or two if we're good about converting all > the docs to the new form, and communicating the new canonical way of doing things.

So, they are exactly same, just format changed, see discusstion about this PR: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/26025

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a bit late, but wanted to share a wider & cleaner image from [The docker Handbook](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-docker-handbook/) about the question:

Previously [...] the generic syntax for this command is as follows:

```
docker run <image name>
```

Although this is a perfectly valid command, there is a better way of dispatching commands to the docker daemon.

Prior to version **1.13**, Docker had only the previously mentioned command syntax. Later on, the command-line was restructured to have the following syntax:

```
docker <object> <command> <options>
```

In this syntax:

> - `<object>` indicates the type of Docker object you'll be manipulating. This can be a ***`container`***, ***`image`***, ***`network`*** or ***`volume`*** object.
> - `<command>` indicates the task to be carried out by the daemon, that is    the run command.
> - `<options>` can be any valid parameter that can override the default    behavior of the command, like the ***`--publish`*** option for port mapping.

Thus,

*`docker container run`* :

1. *`container`* is the object
2. *`run`* is the command to be executed by Docker Daemon.