# What is the difference between docker tag and docker image tag commands?

Tags: docker

What is the difference between the `docker tag` and `docker image tag` commands?

Comment: Compare https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_tag/

Comment: They're the same, but Docker 1.13 (before Docker started doing date-stamped releases) added another optional layer of command hierarchy to group commands together.  Also see [Difference between docker run and docker container run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247609/difference-between-docker-run-and-docker-container-run).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between them; `docker image tag` was just introduced as a more uniform command since it is an action to be taken on an image. Other similar cases exist, like for example, `docker ps` and `docker container ls`, `docker rmi` and `docker image rm`, etc.