# What is the difference between docker pull and docker image pull commands?

Tags: docker

As of now, I am learning Docker. This [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/) has mentioned two ways of pulling an image from the Docker registry. Can anyone explain this in simple terms?

Does this mean that we cannot get updates on a pulled image if we use `docker image pull` command?

Comment: The documentation show multiple pulling examples, what are the 2 ways you are referring to ? There is no `docker image run` command.

Comment: I'm really sorry the for the confusion. I updated the question. I was reading the docker pull command.

Comment: Also see [Difference between docker run and docker container run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247609/difference-between-docker-run-and-docker-container-run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same command. From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-from-docker-hub) you linked:

> To download a particular image, or set of images (i.e., a repository), use `docker image pull` (or the `docker pull` shorthand).

There are many *"shortand commands"* like:

- `docker push` for `docker image push`
- `docker run` for `docker container run`
- ...

Comment: Is the section https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier in the mentioned reference, say docker pull command is for pulling an image by digest, or else is it happening in docker image pull command also?

Comment: Again, those are the same command, registered as aliases in [Docker CLI source code](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/23.0/cli/command/image/pull.go#L40)

Comment: It should be pointed out that the preferred form is `docker image full`, and the short form is retained for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between docker pull and docker image pull commands?

None.

> Can anyone explain this in simple terms?

They are the same.

> Does this mean that we cannot get updates on a pulled image if we use docker image pull command?

No.

Also https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-pull-imagename-vs-docker-image-pull-imagename/59283