# Docker container goes to excited state when i use to start. Why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I am very new to this docker things. I created containers in docker when i use to start my container it suddenly goes to excited state. I am trying to assign port:7050 to that container. All other container which i have created they use start but one orderer container when i use to turn it on, it automatically goes to excited state.

You can refer image :
Error: Container goes to excited state

[image]

Please guide me through this, i am not getting what is the problem. I tried removed all the docker conatiner and again created but i am getting same problem. 
Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: docker logs container_name will show the cause why it is exited.

Comment: Containers exit when whatever you've asked them to do finishes/crashes. I see that your container's `COMMAND` is `orderer`. What is this command supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with 
 `docker run -d` ?
This will prevent the container from exiting.
If for example, you initialize a service and it runs in the background probably the container will understand that it finished its job and it will exit.

You can check this post for more information [Docker container will automatically stop after "docker run -d"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d)

Comment: Yes i have tried but still, not working @Juan Bermudez

Answer (score 1):

First thing would be to check the logs of the pod as with:

```
docker logs $id
```

where you swap $id for the container id as you could see in the image you linked

If that doesn't tell you enough you can also call:

```
docker inspect $id
```