# Docker container keeps stopping after 'docker start'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm fairly new to Docker. I have a long `Dockerfile` that I inherited from a previous developer, which has many errors and I'm trying to get it back to a working point. I commented out most of the file except for just the first line:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

I did the following:

1. `docker build -t pm .` to build the image - this works because I can see the image when I execute `docker images`
2. `docker run <image-id>` returns without error or any message. Now I'm expecting the container to be created from the image and started. But when I do a `docker ps -a` it shows the container exited:

> ```
> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED    STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
> ```
>
> b05f9727f516     f216cfb59484        "/bin/bash"         About a
>   minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago
>   lucid_shirley

Not sure why can't I get a running container and why does it keep stopping after the `docker run` command.

3. executing `docker logs <container_id>` displays nothing - it just returns without any output.

Comment: you could view container's log by `docker logs your-container-id-or-name` and start debugging from there.

Comment: I did that and it showed nothing. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: The machine on which you are running does it have enough memory to run Ubuntu on it? Are you running multiple containers. You can check running containers by `docker ps -a`

Comment: I´d second @Ntwobike answer, if your container doesn´t actually do nothing to keep it running you could add a ``` CMD watch -n1 ls ``` to keep it busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker container categorized following way.

1. Task Based : When container start it will start processing and it complete the process then exited.
2. Background container : It will wait for some request.

As you not provided your docker file so I assume that you have only one statement.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

your build statement create image with name pm.

1. Now you run 
   docker run pm 
   It will start container and stop as you did not provide any entry point.
2. Now try this 
   This is one command prompt or terminal.

   ```
   docker run -it pm /bin/bash
   ```

   Open another terminal or command prompt.

   ```
   docker ps ( Now you will see there is one container).
   ```
3. If you want to see container that is continuously running then use following image.
   (This is just a example)

   ```
   docker run -d -p 8099:80 nginx
   ```

Above line run one container with Nginx image and when you open your browser http://localhost:8099 you can see the response.

Answer (score 5):

Your Docker image doesn’t actually do anything, container stop when finish its job. Since here no foreground process running it will start and then immediately stop.
To confirm your container have no issues, try to put below code into a `docker-compose.yml`(in same folder as the `Dockerfile`)  and run `docker-compose up`, now you will see your container is running without exiting.

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-service:
    build: .
    tty: true
```

Please have a look here [Docker official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#introduction) it will guide you to how to work with docker.

Answer (score 5):

try 
`docker run -it <image> /bin/bash`
to run a shell inside the container.

That won't do much for you, but that'll show you what is happening: as soon as you exit the shell, it will exit the container too.

Your container basically doesn't do anything: it has an image of Ubuntu but doesn't have an ENTRYPOINT or a CMD command to run 'something'
Containers are ephemeral when ran: they run a single command and exit when the command finishes.

Answer (score 2):

Docker Containers are closely related to the process they are running. This process is specified by the "CMD" part on the Dockerfile. This process has the PID "1". If you kill it, your container is killed. If you haven't one, your container will stop instantly. In your case, you have to "override" your CMD. You can do it with a simple : "docker run -it ubuntu:18.04 bash". "-it" is mandatory since it allows the stdin to be attached to your container.

Have fun with docker.

Answer (score 2):

Each instruction of Dockerfile is a layer within a container which perform some task. In your docker file It's just the loading the ubuntu which is completed when you run the docker within a fraction of seconds and exit since process finished. So if want to have your container running all the time then there should be a foreground process running in your docker.
For testing if you run

`docker run <imageid> echo hi` it will return the output means your container is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 3 ways:

#### Check that `CMD` is a long-running process

Ensure your `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` is a long-running or blocking process (like starting an app server, for example), otherwise it will just run and afterwards the container will stop.

#### Use `-t` option

Try using the `-t` option. Example

```
docker run -dt -p 8888:8888 my-image
```

#### Add a long-running command to `CMD` instruction

You can always place a long running or blocking process in your `CMD` instruction. For example if this is your CMD instruction:

```
CMD["sh", "-c", "/runme.sh"]
```

then you could add `&& tail -f /dev/null` to it like so:

```
CMD["sh", "-c", "/runme.sh && tail -f /dev/null"]
```

That's simply giving `CMD` a long-running process, thus keeping your container running. Open another terminal window and run `docker ps` to see the container running.

#### Note

- Related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d) could also be useful