# Container Docker is exited after run

Tags: docker, sonarqube, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM sonarqube

ADD https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/

USER root
RUN  chmod -R 655 /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ &&  chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

When I run the image build:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 sonarqube-test
```

The container is created and  exited.

The docker inspect :

```
[
{
    "Id": "sha256:266ee2202a5d23c7deed92b67c70793d681ff3f46a9b8901586464a9785f0f03",
    "RepoTags": [
        "sonarqube-test:latest"
    ],
    "RepoDigests": [],
    "Parent": "sha256:19fe6021b3c114dc32bb70b276a2aa4c95d05eeba1d98920842290c5682378f4",
    "Comment": "",
    "Created": "2019-05-08T14:20:48.968804549Z",
    "Container": "752779a26450df746105d84c3172e56aef52cf7d7f12f10b594ae6987cc0b147",
    "ContainerConfig": {
        "Hostname": "d0b3d88572d1",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "root",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "9000/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_HOME=/docker-java-home",
            "JAVA_VERSION=8u212",
            "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u212-b01-1~deb9u1",
            "SONAR_VERSION=7.7",
            "SONARQUBE_HOME=/opt/sonarqube",
            "SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar",
            "SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar",
            "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL="
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/sh",
            "-c",
            "chmod -R 655 /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ &&  chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/"
        ],
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "sha256:19fe6021b3c114dc32bb70b276a2aa4c95d05eeba1d98920842290c5682378f4",
        "Volumes": {
            "/opt/sonarqube/data": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/opt/sonarqube",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "./bin/run.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": [],
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "DockerVersion": "17.05.0-ce",
    "Author": "",
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "d0b3d88572d1",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "root",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "9000/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_HOME=/docker-java-home",
            "JAVA_VERSION=8u212",
            "JAVA_DEBIAN_VERSION=8u212-b01-1~deb9u1",
            "SONAR_VERSION=7.7",
            "SONARQUBE_HOME=/opt/sonarqube",
            "SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME=sonar",
            "SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD=sonar",
            "SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL="
        ],
        "Cmd": null,
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "sha256:19fe6021b3c114dc32bb70b276a2aa4c95d05eeba1d98920842290c5682378f4",
        "Volumes": {
            "/opt/sonarqube/data": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/opt/sonarqube",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "./bin/run.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": [],
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "Architecture": "amd64",
    "Os": "linux",
    "Size": 976584087,
    "VirtualSize": 976584087,
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "RootDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/ad0d706f550d36e9ffd088d7e6ebf3454e8679a3587457cb0686719fbb20313b/root"
        },
        "Name": "overlay"
    },
    "RootFS": {
        "Type": "layers",
        "Layers": [
            "sha256:fbb641a8b94349e89886f65d79928e4673530e2a2b4d33c2c95e0426713f78e4",
            "sha256:604829a174eb966a2102e2e68c7669e1fe56721e8d7ea27f9a286aa33be8be20",
            "sha256:12cb127eee44270330891b1b610ce34e81f53a91a22e3a7f53f0632391d99892",
            "sha256:b17cc31e431beb2f39988dff23d04f85ba4b446fc0a13f304774852fa3c87d85",
            "sha256:af5ae48417766c4fa9b5ce9fc30a245c11dcb568c553bcf810c2fc137f62a97a",
            "sha256:e38df31d449cc619dbcab21468926927fdf4eff01498c8090cfddc0fb21e2a8a",
            "sha256:f350d0146bb3e9534f9bf10bfcdda4e413719644c78729f67667e16ffbd90325",
            "sha256:f7d12d4716672cbfdc98d3e431e63f8a5b236ab84ff80057dfadc6d1d0813fef",
            "sha256:3cc1c13e6e626d0073da455dc51b17a905ea5fc48a26e8d3e4d61a4218c105a9",
            "sha256:c6e01c4cf63e8d9b7d5f3de0a7a8d007bff05b3281dc559ebee890a9f79220a3",
            "sha256:e2c38440cb8a6f84bee3e3b2c45504812721cfa68d16fb601f8079873da8db35",
            "sha256:729909524637bf4631190a3112d993b0df9c1039d533f23452257bbe1eea883c",
            "sha256:f96562dd3433e564ae287d48ec2edf22f72cfdb60447e5df0d1caab63cfc2c27",
            "sha256:320c8f5ca5a033919c934ed8e82f8323e6fd0b38278a56a164c2718aa259b89c"
        ]
    }
}
]
```

The docker logs for this ID:

```
2019.05.08 14:22:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2019.05.08 14:22:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2019.05.08 14:22:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
2019.05.08 14:22:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2019.05.08 14:22:59 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2019.05.08 14:22:59 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2019.05.08 14:23:01 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2019.05.08 14:23:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2019.05.08 14:23:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

The root user is as default and the container executes if it is with -it instead of -d by passing /bin/bash like this :`docker run -it sonarqube-test /bin/bash`.

The plugin was correctly copied to the directory and modified for user sonarqube.

Does anyone know why the container is being exited?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user already when you ADD the file:

```
FROM sonarqube

ADD --chown=sonarqube:sonarqube https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

I tested this and it works.

Comment: The cuestion is: "Does anyone know why the container is being exited?" you are not answering the question, you only post a posible solution of the code. But in this case you misread the post. It can happen

Comment: You have a typo in your command: a dot after chown "chown." instead "chown". Try to copy-paste the command in the solution to avoid typos.

Comment: I to copy-paste the command but gave the error that I reported. I do not know why for you it worked and for min not. Maybe the version of Docker. But what he solved was to give the execution permission that was missing.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem add the execution permission that is missing should look like this:

```
FROM sonarqube

ADD https://github.com/gabrie-allaigre/sonar-gitlab-plugin/releases/download/4.0.0/sonar-gitlab-plugin-4.0.0.jar /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/

USER root
RUN  chmod -R 555 /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ &&  chown -R sonarqube.sonarqube /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have an `ENTRYPOINT`, your `/bin/bash` at the end of the docker-run doesn't work with `-d` (with `-it` works perfectly).

You need add `exec tail -f /dev/null` or `while true; do sleep 1000; done` at the end of your `ENTRYPOINT`

`exec tail -f /dev/null` is the most efficient, you can check here: [A flag in docker to always be up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647600/a-flag-in-docker-to-always-be-up)

This is a dockers with this solution:
https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/blob/master/bootstrap.sh

This is an [oficial fedora solution](https://hub.docker.com/_/fedora), they create a `CMD ["/bin/bash"]` at the end:
https://github.com/fedora-cloud/docker-brew-fedora/blob/4dbc2ccd3b4d52258981eaf12043025054d53023/x86_64//Dockerfile

Comment: You usually don’t want a container that does nothing.  The questioner doesn’t either.  If you look at their `docker inspect` and command output their base image has an `ENTRYPOINT`, it’s just not running correctly.

Comment: Can I see your `ENTRYPOINT` `./bin/run.sh`? Maybe you can add at the end `exec tail -f /dev/null`

Comment: the file @PabloLópezGallego talks about is in the original repository of the image (https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/tree/abaf14c38297974eb5de295d42e83066ddb84751/7.7-community) and has nothing to do with your problem. It is obvious from your post that you are not overwriting this startup script.

Comment: @Mihai when an ENTRYPOINT is necessary I change it to create my image more efficiently.

Comment: @PabloLópezGallego and you are not the only one. But in this case you misread the post. It can happen