# How to launch custom script AND cron on container start

Tags: bash, shell, docker, cron

I created a docker image for a cron job (script backup.sh) - it copies files to the remote server for a backup.
but first - when container starts I need to create ssh keys and add it to authorized_keys on the remote server, so I can connect via rsync.

I can't figure out how could I do two tasks on the container start - launch script authorize.sh and cron

- I tried to call authorize.sh within the script backup.sh, but it would be called always at the same time in multiple containers and those ssh key overwrites each other, that's why I need to do it on container start, not inside the cron script
- I can't call the script in the dockerfile on image build, as the remote server connections are passed as environment variables
- I've tried instead of CMD ['crond', '-f', '-d', '8'] do CMD ['authorize.sh', '-f', '-d', '8'] and add crond -f inside the authorize script, but container stops after finishing authorize.sh

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.6

RUN apk update; \
    apk upgrade;

RUN apk add bash openssh-client sshpass rsync

RUN mkdir -p /var/export/

COPY backup.sh /usr/local/bin/backup.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/backup.sh

RUN echo '0 */8 * * *   /usr/local/bin/backup.sh' > /etc/crontabs/root

WORKDIR /var/export/

CMD ["crond", "-f", "-d", "8"]
```

Comment: You can read more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209974/3220113.  Does it help when you use `FROM centos:7` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is how Docker works , when the CMD command finished the container will be stopped.

you can add kind of `loop` or some command that will not finished at the end of your `authorize.sh` somthing like :

```
tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: thanks @linSel, it works. actually it works even with crond -f, I don't understand why it didnt work the first time