# Docker container ports are exposed on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: docker, port

I'm developing an **Ubuntu based** docker image on a windows 10 machine with Docker Desktop.  The image has a server app listening for HTTP traffic on port 5000.  When I run the image locally on Windows using:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 dockerImageName /opt/serverApp
```

Everything works fine, I can go to http://localhost:5000 and see a web interface.

But then I push the image to a repo in Azure then pull it back down onto a Ubuntu Azure VM and execute the same command, the container appears to start correctly but executing:

```
curl http://localhost:5000
```

returns:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused

Not that it should matter but I've also allowed incoming traffic on port 5000 in the network security group the VM is attached to.

If I execute:

```
sudo lsof -i:5000
```

Nothing is returned.

Is this an Azure related issue?  Are there differences between how a Linux image is run on Windows and a VM on Azure (on Windows Docker Desktop uses a Linux VM to run containers)?

Answer (score 0):

Le sigh it was this:
[Docker container will automatically stop after “docker run -d”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d)

Annoying how the behavior changes between Windows and Ubuntu when running containers.