# Docker image fails to run process in foreground mode

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I'm developing a docker image based on nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu18.04.  At build time a custom web server is installed and I have a docker-entrypoint.sh which runs the server depending if an env var is set at run time.

This all works fine if I run the container in interactive mode:

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 -e RUN_SERVER=1 myImage/17.5.360/all /bin/bash
```

Or use the old "hack" to keep the image alive:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000  -e RUN_SERVER=1 myImage/17.5.360/all /bin/bash -c "tail -f /dev/null"
```

But when I follow the most recent answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d/30209974?noredirect=1#comment102149508_30209974):

```
docker run -t -d -p 5000:5000 -e RUN_SERVER=1 myImage/17.5.360/all
```

The image appears to load successfully and is kept alive, but the server is not active.

Here's the abridged version of docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
if [ $RUN_SERVER = "1" ]; then
   runMyServer
fi
exec "$@"
```

And Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-base-ubuntu18.04 AS HInstaller  
ENV RUN_SERVER=0  # Defaults to not run the server

# ...

COPY "./docker-entrypoint.sh" /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

How can I debug what's happening since interactive mode works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entrypoint script ends with the line

```
exec "$@"
```

which means to replace the current process with whatever got passed as command-line arguments.  When there is both an entrypoint and a command, the command gets passed as arguments to the entrypoint.

In your first two examples, you are giving some command on the `docker run` command line, and the container will keep running as long as that stays running.  In your last two examples, absent anything on either the command line or a Dockerfile `CMD` instruction, the command will be empty.  This `exec` line won't do anything, and the entrypoint script will complete successfully.

It's not really good practice to have a container that runs an interactive shell or a meaningless `tail` command, and as a side effect runs some service.  You want to start your service as a foreground process, and make it be the main container process.  It's extra work for a service to start itself in the background so usually there will be some sort of "foreground" option to bypass it.  If you put something like

```
CMD ["runMyServer", "--foreground"]
```

this will run in that `exec "$@"` line.  If your entrypoint script gets reduced to just that line, you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks!  Your first paragraph is the best explanation of exec "$@" I've read.  My entry script starts two processes, should I run the second process with 'exec' so it becomes the main process of the container?

Comment: Probably, yes.  If you want Docker to notice when that second process dies it’d be better still to launch it in a separate container.