# Docker node container cannot start but works locally without docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, npm, docker-compose

Update 3/23: I used author's package.json, npm install on my Mac, upgrade react-scripts to 3.4.0 and Dockerfile to fix a few issues and now this version works: https://github.com/harrywang/my-flask-react-auth/tree/6e65a7deaf89244a41a7c91843f07f4756956f95 however, this does not explain why the previous version did not work.

Update 3/23: if I only replace package.json and package-lock.json at https://github.com/harrywang/my-flask-react-auth/tree/master/services/client with the authors' versions at https://gitlab.com/testdriven/flask-react-auth/-/tree/master/services%2Fclient, it will work. Don't know why.

Following the tutorial at https://testdriven.io/courses/auth-flask-react/

Docker 2.2.0.4 Desktop on Mac

My code repo is at https://github.com/harrywang/my-flask-react-auth, where you can see the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, you can clone and run `docker-compose up -d --build` to reproduce my problem.

When I run `docker-compose up -d --build`, the flask and database containers work well but the node container exits with error code 0 when "Starting the development server..."

One thing I noticed is that I don't see [wds] webpack related info locally on my Mac. I don't know what they are.

[image]

[image]

but when I go to /services/client and run `npm start`, the node server starts and works well locally.

There is no error message during the docker building process. I have spent a few hours on this and cannot figure it out. Please help!! Thanks a lot!!

However, the author's repo at https://gitlab.com/testdriven/flask-react-auth with older versions does not have this issue:
[image]

Comment: please post what you see with this command `docker logs <container name>`

Comment: @Vishrant same as shown in the screenshot above. Thanks.

```
    $ docker logs my-flask-react-auth_client_1

    > client@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
    > react-scripts start

    ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.0.4/
    ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
    ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /usr/src/app/public
    ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
    Starting the development server...
```

Comment: You are mentioning `npm start`, but I cannot identify NodeJS being installed in your [Dockerfile](https://github.com/harrywang/my-flask-react-auth/blob/master/services/users/Dockerfile). Does it make sense?

Comment: @GeorgeTseres thanks, but you are referring the wrong file, the correct one is: https://github.com/harrywang/my-flask-react-auth/blob/master/services/client/Dockerfile

Comment: the docker container will live until the command execution is not complete, in your case, as soon as `CMD ["npm", "start"]` completes, the docker container exits with status `0`

Comment: @Vishrant I just added the author's repo - no problem with same ` CMD ["npm", "start"]`

Comment: Not familiar with React, but here's what I did:
```
docker run -it --entrypoint sh my-flask-react-auth_client
```
Got a shell to a new container and tried to run: `npm start`
This is what I got:
```bash
> client@0.1.0 start /usr/src/app
> react-scripts start

Could not find a required file.
Name: index.html
Searched in: /usr/src/app/public
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524425/2704032

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I am currently working through the same course. I have done every exactly like written in the guide. I was able two start 2 containers, the third one (flask-react-auth_client_1) stoped with 0.

I first tried to get into the container and execute `docker run -it --entrypoint sh <image>` and then `npm start`

No problem was detected. So I did a little research.

Apparently with `react-scripts@3.4.0` or `react-scripts@3.4.1+` it is impossible to run in the background now without the CI flag enabled.

My fix was, to add `CI=true` to the docker-compose.yml under client > environment.

I go the idea from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688

Comment: In my case, just simply add `CI=true` into npm start scrpts, in package.json:
`"start": "CI=true react-scripts start",`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following part is missing from the client app Dockerfile:

```
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY public /usr/src/app/public
```

This will copy the source folders into the Docker image. These two lines can be set above [the following line](https://github.com/harrywang/my-flask-react-auth/blob/master/services/client/Dockerfile#L23) in your Dockerfile.

The way you can troubleshoot such issues is by doing a `docker run -it --entrypoint sh <image>` to spin up a new container and get a shell to it. Then you can run the command that the server intended to run (`npm start` in our case). From there, you can spot errors that may not have been propagated to docker-compose. In our case, the error was the following:

```
react-scripts start Could not find a required file. 
Name: index.html Searched in: /usr/src/app/public
```

Comment: Thanks! but I think   https://github.com/harrywang/my-flask-react-auth/blob/de922bede7d8777724a56fa07fbb6b6670028fe7/docker-compose.yml#L38 this line takes care of copying the files.

Comment: Seems like they are not mounted correctly though. When I used the described method, it seems that the server started correctly without exiting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just simply add `CI=true` into npm start scrpts, in package.json:

```
"start": "CI=true react-scripts start",
```

Thank to **p1umyi** 's answer above

Answer (score 0):

You must include command line on **docker-compose.yml** :

```
version: '3'
services: 
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    command: npm start #this line
    build: .
    ports: 
      - "4001:8081"
```