# docker-compose down timeout

Tags: logging, docker-compose, timeout

Can I stop containers after some timeout (in github workflow actions)?
I need to be sure that I can see logs of running containers and be surethat containers should stop after some time  (for example after 5 min)

Comment: How are the containers started, are they detached ?

Comment: @user216 Does this topic answer to yours? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for answers. I found solution in ' docker-compose up & sleep 300 && docker-compose down'