# Stuck on starting a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm taking my first steps with Node.js and wrap my head around Docker and following the guide here https://www.docker.com/blog/getting-started-with-docker-using-node-jspart-i/ I successfully create the Docker image as logged on terminal

```
vinnytwice@Vinnys-iMac fixit_server_node % docker images          
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
node-docker   latest    483e8ea7d5e8   2 minutes ago   950MB
node          15.14.0   3d3f41722daf   3 days ago      936MB
```

but then the I try to run it with `docker run node-docker` as the guide says

> After running this command you’ll notice that you were not returned to the command prompt

but nothing happens and instead I'm indeed returned to the prompt..

```
vinnytwice@Vinnys-iMac fixit_server_node % docker run node-docker
vinnytwice@Vinnys-iMac fixit_server_node %
```

I suppose there is something wrong in my `Dockerfile`as I'm using my own app and not cloning the one from the guide.
Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15.14.0

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

As when I start my app I use `nodemon server.js` I tried changing to `CMD [ "nodemon", "server.js" ]` but still the same result..

Comment: Have you tried to `brew install node` outside Docker, and then directly run `node index.js` on the host?  (Using this environment might be easier than trying to learn Node _and_ Docker at the same time.)  What's in the `index.js` file?

Comment: Indeed I used brew to install Node and Docker, I see them in my Cellar folder. When I start my app I can either use `npm start` or `node server.js` or `nodemon server.js`, `node index.js`does nothing..

Answer (score 0):

You should list the running processes to see if it is indeed running.

Unless I'm reading bad, this seems to be just a correct behavior, you're starting a docker container, not asking to get inside it.

```
docker container ls
```

This will show the running processes. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_ls/

Once you start a container, you can connect into it, like in a SSH connection.

```
docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash
```

Next time you can try to start the container and connect at the same time:

```
 docker run -it --name <container name>
```

Comment: It should be unusual to need `docker exec` to "connect to it"; you wouldn't get a shell inside the same Node process running outside a container.

Comment: `docker container ls` shows no containers in terminal

Comment: @Vincenzo try to do a `docker run -d --name my-container node-docker`, it will be a detached container (-d) and now you have a name (--name my-container) so it should be easier to find and reference it. Of course you will learn all those things in the same tutorial you're following, but after creating a detached container try another "ls" to see if something shows up.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your comment, you're probably right. I'm trying to help about the "docker part" but I'm not really familiar with Node. Since there is no "node" tag, I didn't paid attention to this possibility as I'm not really aware about Node details.

Comment: @jacksonbenete I addended the node tag, thanks for pointing it out. I run `docker run -d --name my-container node-docker` but the result is the same, listing containers with `docker container ls` lists none as well as `docker ps`, but `docker ps -a` does show containers.. the two I created and the newly detached my-container: `6a5e3b4183dd   node-docker   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago             my-container`. This shows that the container exits as soon as it's run right??

Comment: And found where  the problem is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d even if in the tutorial is not having this issue applying the accepted solution `docker run -d --name my-container2 node-docker tail -f /dev/null` makes the container stay running as the container is run on the foreground..